# When to name file to JS or JSP?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

What type of files should I give the JS and JSP extensions?
What happens if I name a file into a JS file when it should be a JSP and vice versa?

Also, how to know if the file is a servlet?

Comment: `.jsp` contains Java code/HTML...`.js` contains Javascript code...

Answer (score 1):

`.jsp` contains html,java,javascript as well where `.js` contains only javascript code.

Any java file that extend `HttpServlet` class and its necessary methods